# Remote Operation of Toggle Switch

Tags: remote-control, diy, toggle-switch

I'm working in a laboratory environment, where we need to change the state of a few toggle-switches from time to time. As we want more and more remote control in our lab, these toggle-switches need to be operated from remote via USB/LAN or something similar.

The toggle-switches are part of sensitive electronic hardware where I do not want to make any direct changes by soldering.

Has anyone seen an add-on solution or any other idea, how to address this problem?

Comment: See useless device: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apVR5Htz0K4&ab_channel=JeffreyKohler.

Comment: I think transistor has the right idea.  You can probably find the control code on github.  If you're not willing to change the switches you'll have to actuate them.  Are they at least centralized or is one set by the fume hood and one set behind Larry's cubicle, etc?

Comment: thanks, @Transistor, this is basically what I am searching for, though I can't copy it directly. But I can do some research on this now.

Comment: @KH, the switches are in different rooms but easily accessible. The main issue is the need for operation overnight or on weekends.

Comment: tape or 3d print  housing for a soleniod to them